# How to make sql sub-query in OPENJSON function?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm importing json data to relation table with openjson function. It consists field should be import to child table. How to make sub-query in OPENJSON WITH clause?

Database has two tables CourtSession and LigitigationType. CourtSession table has reference on LigitigationType table (LigitigationTypeId - Id). Database diagram is
[image]

sql to import json data:

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = 
N'[
    {
        "date": "11.07.2019 09:00",
        "judge": " Novik V.P",
        "forma": "Criminal proceedings",
        "number": "759/9893/18",
        "involved": "The accused: Deaf Anatoly",
        "description": "Theft",
        "add_address": "01032, Kyiv, Kyiv, street. Zhilyanskaya, 142",
        "courtroom": ""
    },
]'

INSERT INTO CourtSession
SELECT jsonData.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'$.CourtSessions')
        WITH (
           CourtDate DATETIME2 N'$.date',
           Judge NVARCHAR(100) N'$.judge',
           LigitigationTypeId INT (SELECT Id FROM LigitigationType Where JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.forma') = Name),
           CourtNumber NVARCHAR(100) N'$.number',
           Involved NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.involved',
           Description NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.description',
           Address NVARCHAR(300) N'$.add_address',
           CourtRoom NVARCHAR(100) N'$.courtroom'
        ) 
AS jsonData
```

I expect the sub-query find LigitigationTypeId by predicate "JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.forma') = Name" in WITH clause but sql-server returned error "Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'."

Comment: You can't put a sub query inside your `WITH` there. You need to do it outside, either in the `FROM` or the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you need to perform a `JOIN`. Impossible to test, however, seems like it *should* be as simple as:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CourtSession --({Column List Goes here})
SELECT JD.CourtDate,
       JD.Judge,
       LT.ID,
       JD.CourtNumber,
       JD.Involved,
       JD.[Description],
       JD.[Address],
       JD.CourtRoom
FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'$.CourtSessions')
        WITH (CourtDate datetime2 N'$.date',
              Judge nvarchar(100) N'$.judge',
              Forma nvarchar(100) N'$.forma',
              CourtNumber nvarchar(100) N'$.number',
              Involved nvarchar(MAX) N'$.involved',
              [Description] nvarchar(MAX) N'$.description',
              [Address] nvarchar(300) N'$.add_address',
              CourtRoom nvarchar(100) N'$.courtroom') JD
    JOIN dbo.LigitigationType LT ON JD.Forma = LT.[Name];
```